# Remove perfect-scrollbar for mobiles

Tags: css, angular

I am just putting perfect-scrollbar class 'height: auto' on mobile screens, that should do work.
As its working fine in responsive mode on web.
But on mobiles its not getting scroll.

```
@media (max-width: 992px)
{
    .parent-class perfect-scrollbar{
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your class to `.perfect-scrollbar`

```css
@media (max-width: 992px)
{
    .parent-class .perfect-scrollbar{
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this css:

```
.ps__thumb-y {
  width: 0px;
}
```